# Flutter other widget doesn`t show when I call my new created custom widget

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, flutter-ios

Hello when ever I tried to call the bottombar widget (the custom widget that I created) The other widget elements dissapears

here is the home_page.dart code:

```
import 'package:clothing_app/utils/bottom_bar.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:line_awesome_icons/line_awesome_icons.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  int buttonSelected = 1;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: Scaffold(
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomBar(),
        appBar: AppBar(
          elevation: 0,
          backgroundColor: SCAFFOLD_BG_COLOR,
          leading: IconButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            icon: Icon(
              LineAwesomeIcons.bars,
              color: MAIN_BLACK_COLOR,
            ),
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              icon: Icon(
                LineAwesomeIcons.search,
                color: MAIN_BLACK_COLOR,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Expanded(
                          child: SingleChildScrollView(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                vertical: 12, horizontal: 16),
                            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                            child: Row(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                _topSlideItem(),
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 24,
                                ),
                                _topSlideItem(),
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 24,
                                ),
                                _topSlideItem(),
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 24,
                                ),
                                _topSlideItem(),
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 24,
                                ),
                                _topSlideItem(),
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 24,
                                ),
                                _topSlideItem(),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding:
                          EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12, horizontal: 16),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(
                            'Best of the week',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 22, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 24,
                          ),
                          verticalSlideItem(),
                          SizedBox(height: 16),
                          verticalSlideItem(),
                          SizedBox(height: 16),
                          verticalSlideItem(),
                          SizedBox(height: 16),
                          verticalSlideItem(),
                          SizedBox(height: 16),
                          verticalSlideItem(),
                          SizedBox(height: 16),
                          verticalSlideItem(),
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _topSlideItem() {
    return Material(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32),
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 32),
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .55,
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Image.asset(
              'assets/img.jpeg',
              height: 140,
              width: 50,
              fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
            ),
            SizedBox(width: 24),
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    'Flower patterned khaki dress',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 12,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        height: 12,
                        width: 12,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.red,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 8,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        height: 12,
                        width: 12,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 8,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        height: 12,
                        width: 12,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.green,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 12,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    '\$89,99',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 16,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Color.fromRGBO(180, 184, 190, 1),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget verticalSlideItem() {
    return Material(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32),
      color: Colors.transparent,
      child: Container(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24)),
              child: Center(
                child: Image.asset(
                  'assets/img.jpeg',
                  height: 110,
                  width: 80,
                  fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(width: 24),
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    'Flower patterned\nkhaki dress',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 12,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        height: 12,
                        width: 12,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.red,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 8,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        height: 12,
                        width: 12,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 8,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        height: 12,
                        width: 12,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.green,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 12,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    '\$89,99',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 16,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Color.fromRGBO(180, 184, 190, 1),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

here is the custom widget I created (bottom_bar.dart);

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Scaffold(
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.call),
              label: 'Calls',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.camera),
              label: 'Camera',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.chat),
              label: 'Chats',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

here is the main.dart file;

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(App());
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(fontFamily: 'Cera'),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

here is the image when I call the bottom navigationbar;

[image]

and here is an image when I remove the bottom navigationbar code line (`bottomNavigationBar: BottomBar(),`);

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are wrapping your custom BottomNavigationBar with Scaffold and it covers you HomePage Scaffold, so that's why the other widgets couldn't be shown.

Remove the Scaffold from the custom BottomNavigationBar:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return BottomNavigationBar(
    items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.call),
        label: 'Calls',
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.camera),
        label: 'Camera',
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.chat),
        label: 'Chats',
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```